Shell script hangs when run with a shebang line
This didn't used to happen, but now when I try to execute a shell script in my path by name, it just hangs.
The script: ~/bin/foo:
#!/bin/sh

echo this is foo

My PATH:
/usr/bin:/bin

What happens when I try to run it:
$ sh ~/bin/foo
this is foo

$ ~/bin/foo
(hangs forever)

The script's file mode is 0755.
OS is Ventura 13.6.4
Changing the shebang to bash did not help. Changing to zsh did not help.
Python scripts are seeing the same problem.

More information, by request:
I used vim to edit the script. cat bin/foo > bin/bar; chmod +x bin/bar did not fix it. I want to stress that scripts that used to work are now broken.
Problem happens with sh, bash, zsh, and even python3, so I don't think it's a corrupt shell.
I changed the shebang line to #!/usr/bin/env -S -v -i bash and it still hung without generating any output.
/bin/sh $HOME/bin/foo works perfectly.
Piping through xxd was a good idea, but nothing unexpected. Again, problem is happening with all scripts with a shebang line, including old ones that worked before. I just tried it with a script that has a modification date of 2019.
I've double-checked PATH. echo $PATH returns
/usr/bin:/bin

Both sh $HOME/bin/foo and /bin/sh $HOME/bin/foo succeed.

Which shell are you running? What does type sh say?

If you turn on logging in the Console, and then run it, do you see the same problem? Also, what are the file attributes of foo?

Probably related https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/380765/what-makes-catalina-make-a-shell-script-quarantined https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/303016/why-does-macos-set-xattr-com-apple-quarantine-when-saving-a-shell-script-on-a-u

This has started happening for me as well, today.

Problem happens with sh, bash, and python3. type sh returns sh is /bin/sh

Script is not quarantined. ls -leO@ ~/bin/foo returns -rwxr-xr-x  1 falk  staff  - 29 Apr 13 22:12 /Users/falk/bin/foo

Which editor do you use to create the script? If you run cat bin/foo > bar; chmod +x bar; ./bar, does it work

Only change the shebang line to #!/usr/bin/env -S -v -i bash and run ~/bin/foo again, do you see any lines prefixed with #env?

Could it be, that your /bin/sh became corrupt? Doe the script hang too if you explicitly run it with /bin/sh $HOME/bin/foo? If it runs well, do a head -n 1  ~/bin/foo| xxd and look out for conspicuous hex codes.

@user1934428 The head thing is a good idea, the first two points are already covered in the question.

@nohillside : They are partially covered in the question, i.e. if we can trust that the PATH is really the one stated by the OP; and even then, it could be that sh is an alias or a function, and that sh .... is not running /bin/sh. That's why I would do the test with executing the script from the command line by explicitly writing /bin/sh...  I don't trust anything when it comes to such a weird program behaviour.

@user1934428 I'm not going to argue that :-) I just noticed that it also seems to impact zsh and python.

Anyway, please edit the question with the details people asked for in the comment so it can be reopened.

Edits have been made.

Can you switch to another user account (or create one) and try there? If it happens as well, a reasonable next step would be to reinstall macOS from Recovery Mode.

I don't see where you've tested in safe mode. I suggest trying that next.

(1) If you run ~/bin/foo or any bash/zsh/Python scripts without a shebang line, do they still hang? (2) Run set -x in the Terminal and run ~/bin/foo, what debugging output do you see (if any) before it hangs? (3) Start a new Terminal and run touch ~/bin/abc; chmod 755 ~/bin/abc; ~/bin/abc, does it hang? (4) Run mkdir ~/bin2; touch ~/bin2/abc; chmod 755 ~/bin2/abc; ~/bin2/abc, does it hang?
